# Static linking in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, static-linking

The Windows Azure client libraries are very big (several MBs), and I have a fairly small project (on the order of a few hundred KBs) that uses only a few functions from them. Is there a way for me to link in those functions at build time, so that the resultant DLL doesn't get hugely bloated, and I don't have to link the functions in at runtime?

Something like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx, but I get the impression that bundles in the whole DLL.

Thanks!

Edit: Because there are external constraints on the size of the final deliverable DLL, inflating it this much is an absolute last resort - the only other option I'm aware of is just to duplicate the code I use verbatim.

Comment: To paraphrase @BradleyDotNET : No.

Comment: @spender Converted to an answer, that says the same thing :)

Comment: +1 for the technique from Jeffrey Richter

Comment: Considering that reflection will allow you to create references to assemblies at runtime that the linker couldn't possibly know about, static-only linking isn't going to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word: **No**.

Remember that even though you only use a few functions, there are likely many other function in the library that those functions use, that you don't even know about!

You can't do this, because you don't have access to all the dependencies. Remember also that those dependencies may even reside in another DLL, and you need to include *that* entire DLL for the same reason.

Comment: So even if the set of functions I use, even indirectly, is a tiny subset of all the functionality provided by the library, I need to pull in a set of unused and unrelated things in order to use any of them?

Comment: @bfops Yep. The designers chose to encapsulate all that into a library, and there really isn't much you can do about it. If it was *your* library, you could just copy the functions and their dependencies into your project, but since it isn't, you are pretty much stuck.

Comment: Isn't this kind of a problem with C#? In C or C++, I'm fairly certain I can statically link a library and only the functions actually used will end up in the final executable. My options here are massive bloat or code duplication.

Comment: @bfops You could consider it one I suppose. C# wasn't intended for static linking to work like that. For this very reason, many projects are split up into a multitude of interlinked DLLs, so you can only include the ones you need. Of course, this comes with the problem of having to find the 6 out of 100 that are actually necessary. Neither is a perfect world, it just depends on what the system designer thinks is the lesser evil.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for sounds very like [.NET Native](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx).
Unfortunately for you, its only preview and right now works only with Store Apps for devices. Statements like this

> We will continue to evolve and improve native compilation for the range of .NET applications

can be found on the internet but nothing specific about web apps\Azure.

Until then, answer is **No**